# Has anyone found a way to animate hair particals manually?

Tags: animation, particles, hair

I understand you can simulate the hair, but that's not what I want.

It's too laggy, takes too much time, and I never get the results that I want.

The ideal situation I would like would be to select my subject, switch to particle edit, then scrub through the animation combing the hair to where I would like it to be and adding key frames for it.

Comment: I don't think combing animation is possible, but you can guide the hair with curves. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vu6MQC6qdRY

Comment: You cab try to use keyed particles with hair system. This gives a rather cumbersome system, but you can at least TRY.